# Liquibase for managing procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, liquibase

I just came into know about Liquibase. I already started the project, and my database have few store procedures and few tables. Now I want to take a dump of all database via liquebase. For dumping the database table structure i uses `liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --classpath=lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar --changeLogFile=dump/db.master.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" --username=root generateChangeLog`
and for dumping the data from the table i uses liquibase --`driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --classpath=lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar --changeLogFile=dump/db.master.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" --username=root --diffTypes="data" generateChangeLog`
But I am unable to get those procedure to dump in that XML file.
If any one has any idea on this
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Liquibase can't export procedures. In my project, i do it manually.